# Return and update values from an object

Tags: javascript

I'm using an animation library that uses "scenes". Scenes are structured like this:

```js
const animations = animationLibrary({
    scenes: {
        sceneOne: {
            appear() {
                // do something when scene appears
            },
            disappear() {
                // do something when scene disappears
            }
        },
        sceneTwo: {
            appear() {
                // do something when scene appears
            },
            disappear() {
                // do something when scene disappears
            }
        },
    }
})
```

I have a lot of scenes, 40 or so, for a large project. In the past for this project, scope has not been an issue, as I generally do not need to be accessing the same variable in multiple functions, so it works for me to just define a variable inside a function and use it there. However, there are a growing number of cases where I would like to execute a setInterval in one method and a clearInterval in a different function. I am currently doing that like this:

```js
var setIntervalId;

const animations = animationLibrary({
    scenes: {
        sceneOne: {
            appear() {
                setIntervalId = setInterval(myFunc, 1000)
            },
            disappear() {
                clearIntervalId(setIntervalId)
            }
        },
    }
})
```

The problem I am having is as the main scenes object grows, with many scenes inside of it, it seems badly organized to have a number of variables, unrelated to each other, stored outside of the animations const for scope reasons. I have tried writing my own functions inside of a scene, or adding objects inside scenes to store values, but whenever I try to return them inside a function I'm getting undefined errors in the console.

Is there a way for me to store variables or an object of values that is nested inside a single scene and still be able to access and update those variables/values across functions within that same single scene?

Comment: This is a good use for a class. Each instance can have its own `setIntervalId` and other variables.

Comment: Array/Map IDs for global; For private, you can use callback functions that never need outside referencing it's contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to create a separate variable scope for each of your scene objects.

```js
const animations = animationLibrary({
    scenes: {
        sceneOne: (function () {
            var setIntervalId;
            return {
                appear() {
                    setIntervalId = setInterval(myFunc, 1000)
                },
                disappear() {
                    clearInterval(setIntervalId)
                }
            };
        })()
    }
})
```

You could probably use factory method `createScene()` for creating scene objects with less code. But in this case, your animation library must always call `appear()` and `disappear()` methods on the scene object (e.g. `scenes.sceneOne.appear()`), otherwise it will not work due to different meaning of the `this` keyword.

```js
const animations = animationLibrary({
    scenes: {
        sceneOne: createScene(
            function () {
                this.setIntervalId = setInterval(myFunc, 1000)
            },
            function () {
                clearInterval(this.setIntervalId)
            }
        )
    }
})

function createScene(appearFunc, disappearFunc) {
    return {
        appear: appearFunc,
        disappear: disappearFunc,
        setIntervalId: undefined
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a property for interval as well.

```js
let animation = {
  scenes: {
    sceneOne: {
      intervalRef:null,
      count:0,
      appear() {
        console.log("Start");
        this.intervalRef = setInterval(()=> console.log(this.count++), 1000);
      },
      disappear() {
        console.log("Finish");
        clearInterval(this.intervalRef);
      },
    },
  },
};

animation.scenes.sceneOne.appear();
setTimeout(()=>{
  animation.scenes.sceneOne.disappear();
},5000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could approach the topic with [JS Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

## Scene Class

```js
class Scene {

  constructor(intervalId, data, callBack) {
    this.intervalId = intervalId;
    this.data = data;
    this.callBack = callBack;
  }

  appear() {
    // do something when scene appears
    console.log('appear');
  }

  disappear() {
    // do something when scene disappears
    console.log('disappear');
  }

  getData(key) {
    return this.data[key];
  }

  foo() {
    console.log('foo(): bar');
  }

  bar() {
    console.log('class callBack function');
    this.callBack();
  }

}
```

## Instantiation

```js
const callBack = () => { console.log('passed callBack function'); };

let scene = new Scene(1, {foo: 'bar'}, callBack);

let scene2 = new Scene(2, { foo: scene.getData('foo') }, callBack);

let scene3 = new Scene(3, scene.data, callBack);
```

## In your case

```js
const animations = animationLibrary({
  scenes: {
    sceneOne: scene,
    sceneTwo: scene2,
    sceneThree: scene3,
    sceneFour: new Scene(4, {lorem: 'ipsum'}, function() {console.log('pass another callback');})
  },
});
```

## Output

```js
scene.appear();
// appear

scene.getData('foo');
// "bar"

scene.foo();
// foo(): bar

scene.bar();
// class callBack function
// passed callBack function
```